# "Stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document" error during loop

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I have this code where I scrape the product links of a webstore main page and then try to loop through all of the links to scrape info from each product.

This code works just fine on the first loop (it opens the first product page and then goes back to the main page), but on the second loop I get the error message "stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document".

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait_variable = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

product_links = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, './/a[@class="product-item-link"]')

for link in product_links:
    wait_variable.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(link)).click()
    
    #Scrape info from product
    
    driver.back()
```

Answer (score 0):

The `StaleElementReferenceException` occurs when you're trying to use a previously-found element that is no longer present on the web page you're on. This happens if you leave the page, even if you later go back to the same one. You'll need to re-find the element in order to work with it, and you'll have to rethink how you use the loop that you have there, which won't work. Perhaps scrape the link and then open it in a new tab so that you don't need to leave the starting page during the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.
Since the webpage has a fixed number of products, I fixed the code by changing the loop to the following:

`products_in_page = 20
while x < 20:
link=wait_variable.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, './/a[@class="product-item-link"]'))[x]
link.click()
#Scrape info from product
driver.back()`